# Pass user object to controller through request from jwt middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, request, jwt, middleware

I have a simple case and I need your advice. I am using tymon jwt package. I have JWT middleware and this is the part of it's code:

```
     $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
     if(!$user){
         return response()->json(['message'=>trans("responseMessages.user_not_exists")], 403);
     }
     $request->request->set('user', $user);
```

what this middleware does, is that it tries to create $user from given jwt token, if it succeeds, user is good to continue. so here is my question, in this code (final line) I pass user object to controller through request, so I can directly have access to user model in controller. I am just interested, is this a good idea? or maybe this will be problematic?

other option is to write `$user = JWTAuth::toUser(JWTAuth::getToken())` in controller function or pass user id through request instead of whole model. but in these cases I communicate with database twice, in middleware and in controller in order to get user object.

also I tried to do something like that in controller constructor : `$this->user = JWTAuth::toUser(JWTAuth::getToken())`, but controller constructor executes before middleware so this one was problematic. so provide me with your ideas and advices if passing user model is good idea or not.

Comment: you can use  $request->merge(array("user" => $user));
instead of 
$request->request->set('user', $user);

Comment: why, what is the point?

Comment: Because In laravel >= 5 you can use $request->merge in the middleware: for more info you can check at https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an opinionated question, so don't take my answer as your final solution.

I use Slim and made an authenticate-middleware that adds the user object to the request attributes. This is essentially what you are doing.

Keep in mind the folllowing problems though (at least with immutables Request/Response objects like with PSR7):

1. when you have middlewares BEFORE your authentication middleware (like catching Exceptions), the request does NOT have the user object, because the middlewares work in layers.
2. Vice versa: if you have middleware that first executes all other middleware and than executes itself

It's just pseudo-code, but you get the idea.

```
middlewarefunction($request, $response, $nextmiddleware) 
{
  $nextmiddleware->do($request, $response);
  // from here on the $request has nothing set to the request by the $nextMiddleware
  // because it is immutable
}
```

// Edit
If you look at other middlewares, they are setting the request attribute with the decoded JWT token too:
https://github.com/DASPRiD/Helios/blob/master/src/IdentityMiddleware.php
https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth/blob/3.x/src/JwtAuthentication.php